# How to list change in sales from previous working days

Tags: postgresql

I have a sales table as this:

| date | Item | net_sale |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023/01/02 | Milk | 500 |
| 2023/01/03 | Milk | 700 |
| 2023/01/04 | Milk | 600 |
| 2023/01/05 | Milk | 300 |
| 2023/01/06 | Milk | 1100 |
| 2023/01/09 | Milk | 900 |
| 2023/01/10 | Milk | 1000 |
| 2023/01/11 | Milk | 800 |

I want a join query, which shows net change in sales compare to previous day, considering weekend is closed so no data. (e.g. 7th and 8th in table)

My desired output should be like this:

| date | Item | net_sale | change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023/01/02 | Milk | 500 | NULL |
| 2023/01/03 | Milk | 700 | 200 |
| 2023/01/04 | Milk | 600 | -100 |
| 2023/01/05 | Milk | 300 | -300 |
| 2023/01/06 | Milk | 1100 | 800 |
| 2023/01/09 | Milk | 900 | -200 |
| 2023/01/10 | Milk | 1000 | 100 |
| 2023/01/11 | Milk | 800 | -200 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`LAG`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) window function to get the previous "*net_sale*" value and subtract it from your current value.

```
SELECT *, 
       net_sale - LAG(net_sale) OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY date) AS change
FROM tab
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ZMj6L4LyNoGoe3KDWGu1E/0).